# How to make Jersey @RolesAllowed with @Stateless work?

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, ejb-3.1

I'm not sure whether this is possible or not but I'm trying to setup a EJB + JAX-RS (Jersey) test project and use the @RolesAllowed annotation.

I'm currently getting the following error logs:

```
Warning:   WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
Severe:   ejb.stateless_ejbcreate_exception
Warning:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB TestSB, method: public java.util.List rest.sb.TestSB.findAll()
Warning:   javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
```

Relevant classes:

ApplicationConfig.java

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        packages("rest");
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
    }
}
```

TestSBFacade.java

```
@Local
public interface TestSBFacade {

    public List<Test> findAll();
}
```

TestSB.java

```
@Stateless
@Path("secured/test")
public class TestSB implements TestSBFacade {

    @DAO @Inject
    private TestDAOFacade dao;

    @Context
    SecurityContext securityContext;

    @Secured
    @RolesAllowed({"READ"})
    @Path("all")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Override
    public List<Test> findAll() {
        //this works without the @RolesAllowed so it is a possible workaroud for now.

        System.out.println(securityContext.isUserInRole("READ")); //output: true
        return dao.findAll();
    }
}
```

AuthFilter.java

```
@Provider
@Secured //NameBinding
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        String token = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        try {
            verifyToken();
            createSecurityContext();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, "Invalid or Expired JWT");
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }

    }
}
```

My SecurityContext is set and working, the @RolesAllowed seems to be to problem since I get no errors if I remove it and a JSON is properly returned to the front-end. Keeping the @RolesAllowed results in the errors mentioned at the start.

However I'd like to use the handy annotation instead of embedding every method inside isUserInRole IF Statements. Any help and insights are much appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that adding the `@RolesAllowed` annotation causes the error you mentioned in the beginning of your post?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Yes, I'll try to clarify it on the question

Comment: Why are you using both Servlet level security and your own custom filter security? It seems that you are doing your authentication in the Jersey filter, and the RolesAllowedDynamicFeature handles the authorization. So why then are you configuring the Servlet security in your web.xml? And why use `DeclaredRoles`? This is something for EJB. The Jersey support for `@RolesAllowed` and the EJB support for it are different systems. You already have everything configured for the Jersey support, so I don't know why you are also trying to use the EJB support.

Comment: You can test it. Try to remove anything related to EJB (and the web.xml security configuration), just to see that the authentication and authorization are working as expected.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thanks for the comments, integrating all of this is new to me and I do not yet completely understand every aspect of it. I removed the security config in the web.xml as well as the `@DeclaredRoles`. Indeed I'm still getting the same result, so I guess it simplifies the problem. Furthermore, are you implying that I should remove the `@Stateless` and `@Local` interfaces? I was under the impression that EJB and JAX-RS were supposed to fulfill different purposes, even though there is apparently some overlap.

Comment: It is just a test to see if all the security it working without EJB. So yes, just to test, remove anything related to EJB. Just mock out the data for now. If all the security works as expected, then we know for sure that it is a problem with the EJB security "overlap". You can try to figure out something from there.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Yes, it actually did work as expected by removing `@Stateless` and `@Local`. I tried then to separate the rest service and inject the `@EJB` into it but to no avail, same errors.

Comment: Maybe try to use CDI instead of EJB. CDI integrates with JPA (I'm assuming that's why you are using EJB)

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can just make your own `@RolesAllowed` annotation and just copy the source code for the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`. And just use that. It seems that just the presence of the real `@RolesAllowed` annotations causes the EJB security to kick in. So If we use our own annotation, we can work around this.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha sorry I didn't answer sooner, I had to shift my attention away for awhile. I have a few different uses for EJB that CDI does not quite cover so I ratter keep it this way for now. So I went for the 'worst scenario', thanks for the hint. I'll be posting my solution shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently due to both EJB and JAX-RS implementations using`@RolesAllowed` they don't do well together. So I decided to create my own Annotation instead and register my own DynamicFeature in the `ApplicationConfig.java`.

Authorized.java

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Authorized {
    public String[] value() default "";
}
```

AuthorizationDynamicFeature.java

```
public class AuthorizationDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceInfo resourceInfo, final FeatureContext featureContext) {

        Authorized auth = new AnnotatedMethod(resourceInfo.getResourceMethod()).getAnnotation(Authorized.class);
        if (auth != null) {
            featureContext.register(new AuthorizationRequestFilter(auth.value()));
        }
    }

    @Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
    private static class AuthorizationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

        private final String[] roles;

        AuthorizationRequestFilter() {
            this.roles = null;
        }

        AuthorizationRequestFilter(final String[] roles) {
            this.roles = roles;
        }

        @Override
        public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
            if (!this.roles[0].isEmpty()) {
                for (final String role : this.roles) {
                    if (requestContext.getSecurityContext().isUserInRole(role)) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                throw new ForbiddenException(LocalizationMessages.USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Huge thanks to @PaulSamsotha for leading me to a more suitable solution.